# how to solve orientation issue in ios7?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ipad-2

I am working on **orientation** in **ios7**

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}

/**
 Changing frame depending on mode
 @param interfaceOrientation is UIInterfaceOrientationobject
 @param duration is NSTimeInterval object
 */
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
        toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        [self landscapeViewFrame];
    }
    else if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        [self portraitViewFrame];
    }
}
```

where `landscapeViewFrame` contains code for landscape View (frames) and `portraitViewFrame` contains frames for portrait View.These methods used to work, but after **upgrading to ios7** they are not responding and not been called, I googled and found these methods are no longer supported.I have tried the other methods

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;//UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait|| UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);

}


- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    if (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {

    }
    else if ([self interfaceOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft||[self interfaceOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
}
```

but only `shouldAutorotate` is called the others are not called . Which methods should be replaced in place of those two. Which method should be used/replaced for `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation`. please help me.

Comment: Are you using UINavigationController?

Comment: no i am not using UINavigationController